# How to replace Img tag with iframe tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with javascript little bit, I want to replace img tag with iframe using javascript in my webpage.

I have tried making script for it from external javascript source but couldn't solve this problem.

```js
<script>
let im = document.getElementById('image');

im.style.display = "none";
im.innerHTML = "<iframe src='http://exampleinthe.io/mage.jpg>" + "</iframe>";
</script>
```

```html
    <img src="image.jpg" id="image">
```

Nothing shows in webpage.

Comment: Images have no innerHTML

Comment: Putting *inside* is not the same as *replacing*

Comment: is there any solution to make it happen..